# C skipping getch

Tags: c, scanf, getch

I was surprised when i saw that in some cases C is skipping some inputs. In my case I'm using Ubuntu with Code::Blocks(xterm). For example, if i have following part of code :

```
scanf("%d",&someInt);
getch();
```

I can input a number,but pressing enter,it saves value for someInt and sends ENTER char automatically to getch(). I was expected for my program to wait to press any key after inputing number and pressing enter. But this not happen. I have found a solution to this, but this isn't a good one.

```
scanf("%d",&someInt);
getch();
getch();
```

Using two **getch()** it solves my problem. I'm entering number and I must press any key to continue. Why this happens ? How to solve it ?

Comment: Are you sure it is `getch` and not `getchar` that you're using?

Comment: getchar() , sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

`getch()` reads a character and in your case it is reading a `\n` because after reading `someint` a newline character is left in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can include newline char in the `scanf` format:

```
scanf("%d\n", &someInt);
getch();
```